# Git difftool allowing to make changes on both side

Tags: git, diff, git-difftool

I would like to do a `git difftool` to make changes on both, the left and the right side.

Suppose that I am working on a branch named `feature` on which I found and corrected some cosmetic issues such as indentation or spelling errors. However I don't want these changes to be part of my final merge with `master` because they are not part of the implemented feature.

So what I usually do is `checkout -b small_fixes master` and `git difftool feature`. I then import all the minor changes on that branch and eventually  I `git rebase master && git branch -d small_fixes`.

Now I have much less differences between `master` and `features` and all these differences are strictly related to the feature. It allows me to do a proper code review before the final `git merge --squash feature`.

The main problem here is that `git difftool master` have temporary files on the left side (`master`). I can make changes on the working copy but not the master. So if I want to change both sides, I need two distinct operations.

I am wondering if there is a tool that can allow to save the changes on the temporary files then `commit` or `stash` them on the master branch.

Note that this situation also appear during a `git difftool --dir-diff` on which both sides are temporary files.

So, the question is: how can I use `difftool` to make changes on both sides, then commit these changes simultaneously?